# Its really possible to use custom template for "home page" in "socialengine"?

Tags: php, socialengine

i already customized header & footer by CSS. Now i want to rearrange the home page with new html elements.

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you should address to `application/modules/core/layouts/default.tpl`.

Check the CSS classes to further alter the style and display of your network.

Answer (score 1):

We recommend first adding or changing CSS rules in the `themes.css` or `constants.css` files which can be found and edited in the *Theme Editor*.

1. For more information about the Theme Editor, please see: http://support.socialengine.com/questions/210/Admin-Panel-Layout-Theme-Editor
2. Further CSS editing of the header and footer can be modified in the

   ```
   /application/modules/Core/externals/styles/main.css file.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way:

Create a simple widget put your all HTML in that and through layout manager render it to home page. Through this you would need not to change core files.

To create a widget refer below user:

http://jadb.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/socialengine-4-create-a-widget/